# Whats the best way to shrink a large body of text?

Tags: encryption

Suppose im given a large essay. Whats the best method available to shrink it down into a small string of letters which I can decode later?  Suppose Im allowed to keep a set of predefined keys if i need to?

Comment: Are you wanting to encrypt it or compress it?

Comment: You could print it, make a photo of it and store it in a dot within the string of letters using a microfiche. Seriously, provide a better description of what you want to achieve, which characters are valid, what kind of encryption etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text is English and you want to minimize the size of the "small string", you will find a number of algorithms here: http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/text.php

For ease-of-implementation, however, you might simply want to use zlib, as it's generally available.

Further, if you want to encrypt the compressed text, you should use AES in CTR mode (and possibly appending an HMAC; ref: http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html).

Finally, assuming that by "asring of letters" you meant "a string of letters", you could base-64 encode the encrypted data, which would give you a string of letters, numbers, and a limited amount of punctuation.